# nodejs: q denodeify does not call functions in then, fail, or fin?

Tags: javascript, node.js, q

Below is my code:

```
var q = require('q');

function Add(cb) {
  var a,b,c;
  a = 5;
  b = 6;
  c = a + b;
  console.log("inside");
  cb(null, 123);
}

var add_promise = q.denodeify(Add);

add_promise(function() {console.log("i am cb")}).then(function(){
  console.log("ok");
}, function(err) {console.log("failed? " + err);}).fail(function(err){
  console.log("error: " + err);
}).fin(function() {
  console.log("final");
});

console.log("outside");
```

I have tried running it in my local machine or on https://repl.it/repls/NiceDeeppinkSandboxes, but it only outputs

```
outside
inside
i am cb
```

instead of any of those "ok", "failed", "error", or "final". Why?

Comment: function Add isn't even asynchronous, nor does it need to be "denodeify"'d - why would you need to do this to your code?

Comment: I am just trying to see how denodeify works. I thought denodeify works on synchronous functions to make them asynchronous?

Comment: you'd need to do something like `function Add(cb) {` ... and instead of returning 123, `cb(null, 123)` - that way, denodeify can do it's job - or, you can do `cb('error')` to see how error handling happens

Comment: No, denodeify works on functions with "node style" callback, and turns them into a promise .

Comment: If you want to see how denodeify works, just look at the [code](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/master/q.js#L1942)

Comment: I modified the code to "Add(cb)" as suggested but it still does not call any functions in then, fail or fin. Will look at the implementation of denodeify to understand it more.

Comment: because you added a callback function, which you **should not do** (denodeify replaces that function!)... try `add_promise().then(function(){`

Comment: Now built into node.js, [`util.promisify()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original).

Comment: Thanks, Jaromanda, that works.

Answer (score 0):

.denodeify method is used to make it easier to interoperate with node.js code. It will add a callback to any calls to the function, and use that to fullfill or reject the promise.

If the function returns a Promise, the state of that Promise will be used instead of the callback.

Check below code snippet:

```
var Promise = require('promise');
var fs = require('fs');

var write = Promise.denodeify(fs.writeFile)


// Example #1: Using promisified functions
// Important!! .then() and .catch() need to be passed in a function!
var promise = write('bla.txt', 'Blablabla', 'utf-8')
                .then(function(){console.log('Success!')})
                .catch(function(err){console.log('Error occured: ' + err)})


// Example #2: Creating a promise myself
function readFile(filename){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

        fs.readFile(filename, 'utf-8', function(err, data){
            if(err) reject(err);
            else resolve(data)
        });

    });
}

readFile('bla.txt')
    .then(function(results){console.log('Success! Here are the results: ', results)})
    .catch(function(err){console.error('Error during operation: ', err)})
```